# Difference between <function prop="Hello"> and {function("Hello")}

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning React and I do not understand when should I use these and when should I not? I have seen tutorials where people just use them seemingly interchangeably. Hence, I would like to know what is the differences between them and when should i or should i not use them.

For example, assuming the "function" named component returns a `<div>Hello</div>` after the call, I can have the following code.

```
import {function} from './component';

class X extends React.Component{

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <function Props1="Hello"/>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Next,I believe can also have the following code, please correct me if I'm wrong

```
import {function} from './component';

class X extends React.Component{

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            {function("Hello")}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

So it seems like there are two ways for doing the exact same thing in ReactJS? Are there any reasons I should be using one over the other?

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I have looked through the article but I'm unsure how does it answer my question, as it explains on the difference between a functional component and a class component. @codekaizer

Comment: There isn't a use case like in your second example. If you try to use a component like this, you can't get the advantages of React probably. You are overriding `props` parameter there. So, how can React handle all the changes? Also, try to pick the components' name starting with a capital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render it like `<function Props1="Hello"/>`, React will create a props object, with the properties and values pairs you passed to it.

When you render it like `{function("Hello")` your props argument will be a string "Hello".

See snippet below:

```js
function App() {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component1
        props1="hello"
      />
      {Component2("hello")}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      Component1
      <div>Props: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
      <br/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component2(props) {
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      Component2
      <div>Props: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Hello, based on the answer, it seems like they are both valid syntax. The only difference is `{function("Hello")}` will return me a String where I overwritten the "Props" object. On the other hand using `<function Props1="Hello">` I will make use of the `Props` object and append another object into it called `Props1` which will contain `Hello`. Am I correct with this assumption?

Comment: Your assumption is correct but it is `props`, not `Props` object. [See the related React code yourself](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js). The syntax might be valid but there isn't any use case like this.

Comment: Kind of. In my example, both will return the "creation" (JSX is transpiled insto `React.createElement`) of a `div` element with the values of the `props` parameter will be accessible to it. The React pattern tells you to use it as an object, by setting as many property/values as you want. When you call it like a normal function, your overriding this behavior and it's for sure a anti-pattern and may cause you some trouble. I don't recommend it. For example, React has a features to memoize components by shallow comparing the `props` object which probably won't work if `props` is not an object.

Comment: I see, both of your replies made it clearer for me. So generally, when attempting to access classes or components outside of my current `file.js` scope I should aim to make use of props to pass values using `<function props1="Hello">`. On the other, hand functional components is only mainly used within my `file.js` scope.

Comment: I didn't understand the other answer to be honest. I think you always should stick to the object syntax. That's the way React was made to work. Either with classes or functional components. The only difference is how you access thoses props. Classes you go `this.props.myProp1` and functional you go `props.myProp1`. You can also have Higher Order Components (HOC) that you can wrap your components with to enhance functionality, but that's a different subject. You should always use `props` as an object.

Comment: You are digging the wrong hole I think :) Your question is not related to class components vs functional components. You are following a wrong syntax here. Create your components with the usual ways and use them in usual ways. `import MyComp from "./somewhere"` and render it there as `<MyComp name="foo" age={15} />` and use those props in your `MyComp` component as `<p>{props.name}-{props.age}</p>`

Comment: I see, I am most likely digging the wrong hole haha. But similar to what you stated I'm thinking along the lines on using `<MyComp name = "foo" age=15 />` when importing components for usage. On the other hand I will use `{this.MyFunc()}` only for calling functions such as `MyFunc(){....}` that is found in the same scope as my current file. I hope this is the correct mindset for react.

Comment: You sure can call regular Javascript functions like that. No problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that first case it is stateful component, so the props has to be passed by something like in your case

> Props1=""

then in your function component which in this case is stateful ,you get access to props via `this.props.Props1`

in second case it is functional component so you can get access to it like for example:

```
class X extends React.Component{

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            {function("Hello")}
         </div>
      )
   }
}


function function(myprop) {
  return <div>{myprop}</div>
}
```